# Deriving attributes from an AWS Cognito SessionToken

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito Federated Services, and obtaining a SessionToken for authorization within API Gateway.

My question... is there a way to obtain user information, or even the cognitoID, from the session token. For example, can we derive the CognitoID from the session token within a micro service and then use that CognitoID to fetch user data (e.g. issuer, subject, first/last name, etc.) from Cognito Federated Identities?

Thanks in advance.
Randy

Comment: JWT token contains user id, but are you getting a jwt token when using federated tokens

Comment: Is your “SessionToken for authorization” the result of an authentication call to a Cognito user pool, or an exchange through a Cognito identity pool?

Comment: SessionToken for authorization is the result of an exchange through a Cognito Identity Pool